# How do you decide that you have tested enough hyper-parameter combinations for a specific neural network architecture?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, optimization, hyperparameter-optimization

**How do you decide that you have tested enough hyper-parameter combinations for a specific neural network architecture to discard it and move on to a new model?**

Do you have a structured (generic) approach? In practice, what gives you the necessary performance (e.g. >= 80% accuracy) the fastest (w.r.t. to your work-hours) assuming there is no SOTA that easily exceeds your requirements and extensive hyper-parameter optimization is infeasible?

Comment: I would personally go the other way around. Test several architectures from the literature with default hyperparameters, select the model that perform best, and then go full tank on fine tuning. The logic being that hyperparameters optimization can only boost by a small margin already decent results.